# Calculating Execution time of each iteration in 'With Recursive' SQL query and Duckdb

Tags: sql, duckdb

I am working on a project in which I have to get the execution time of each iteration by using SQL and duckdb. The iterations are performed in the 'with recursive' part. Following is the query.

```
`drop table if exists iris;
drop table if exists iris2;
drop table if exists img;
drop table if exists one_hot;
drop table if exists w_xh;
drop table if exists w_ho;



create table if not exists iris (sepal_length float,sepal_width float,petal_length float,petal_width float,species int);
copy iris from './iris.csv' delimiter ',' HEADER CSV;
create table if not exists iris2 (id int, sepal_length float,sepal_width float,petal_length float,petal_width float,species int);
insert into iris2 (select row_number() over (), * from iris);
--insert into iris2 (values (1,5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,0));
create table if not exists img (i int, j int, v float);
create table if not exists one_hot(i int, j int, v int, dummy int);
insert into img (select id,1,sepal_length/10 from iris2);
insert into img (select id,2,sepal_width/10 from iris2);
insert into img (select id,3,petal_length/10 from iris2);
insert into img (select id,4,petal_width/10 from iris2);
insert into one_hot(select n.i, n.j, coalesce(i.v,0), i.v from (select id,species+1 as species,1 as v from iris2) i right outer join (select a.a as i, b.b as j from (select generate_series as a from generate_series(1,150)) a, (select generate_series as b from generate_series(1,4)) b) n on n.i=i.id and n.j=i.species order by i,j);

create table if not exists w_xh (i int, j int, v float);
create table if not exists w_ho (i int, j int, v float);
--\i weights.sql
insert into w_xh (select i.*,j.*,random()*2-1 from generate_series(1,4) i, generate_series(1,20) j);
insert into w_ho (select i.*,j.*,random()*2-1 from generate_series(1,20) i, generate_series(1,3) j);

with recursive w (iter,id,i,j,v) as (
  
  (select 0,0,* from w_xh union select 0,1,* from w_ho)
  union all
  (
  --This is the recursive part, an iteration starts from here
  with w_now as (
     SELECT * from w
  ), a_xh(i,j,v) as (
     SELECT m.i, n.j, 1/(1+exp(-SUM (m.v*n.v)))
     FROM img AS m INNER JOIN w_now AS n ON m.j=n.i
     WHERE n.id=0 and n.iter=(select max(iter) from w_now) -- w_xh
     GROUP BY m.i, n.j
  ), a_ho(i,j,v) as (
     SELECT m.i, n.j, 1/(1+exp(-SUM (m.v*n.v))) --sig(SUM (m.v*n.v))
     FROM a_xh AS m INNER JOIN w_now AS n ON m.j=n.i
     WHERE n.id=1 and n.iter=(select max(iter) from w_now)  -- w_ho
     GROUP BY m.i, n.j
  ), l_ho(i,j,v) as (
     select m.i, m.j, 2*(m.v-n.v)
     from a_ho AS m INNER JOIN one_hot AS n ON m.i=n.i AND m.j=n.j
  ), d_ho(i,j,v) as (
     select m.i, m.j, m.v*n.v*(1-n.v)
     from l_ho AS m INNER JOIN a_ho AS n ON m.i=n.i AND m.j=n.j
  ), l_xh(i,j,v) as (
     SELECT m.i, n.i as j, (SUM (m.v*n.v)) -- transpose
     FROM d_ho AS m INNER JOIN w_now AS n ON m.j=n.j
     WHERE n.id=1 and n.iter=(select max(iter) from w_now)  -- w_ho
     GROUP BY m.i, n.i
  ), d_xh(i,j,v) as (
     select m.i, m.j, m.v*n.v*(1-n.v)
     from l_xh AS m INNER JOIN a_xh AS n ON m.i=n.i AND m.j=n.j
  ), d_w(id,i,j,v) as (
     SELECT 0, m.j as i, n.j, (SUM (m.v*n.v))
     FROM img AS m INNER JOIN d_xh AS n ON m.i=n.i
     GROUP BY m.j, n.j
     union
     SELECT 1, m.j as i, n.j, (SUM (m.v*n.v))
     FROM a_xh AS m INNER JOIN d_ho AS n ON m.i=n.i
     GROUP BY m.j, n.j
  )
  select iter+1, w.id, w.i, w.j, w.v - 0.01 * d_w.v
  from w_now as w, d_w
  where iter < 20 and w.id=d_w.id and w.i=d_w.i and w.j=d_w.j
  --and it ends here
  )
)
SELECT iter, count(*)::float/(select count(distinct i) from one_hot)
FROM (
   SELECT *, rank() over (partition by m.i,iter order by v desc) as rank
   FROM (
      SELECT m.i, n.j, 1/(1+exp(-SUM (m.v*n.v))) as v, m.iter
      FROM (
         SELECT m.i, n.j, 1/(1+exp(-SUM (m.v*n.v))) as v, iter
         FROM img AS m INNER JOIN w AS n ON m.j=n.i
         WHERE n.id=0 -- and n.iter=(select max(iter) from w)
         GROUP BY m.i, n.j, iter ) AS m INNER JOIN w AS n ON m.j=n.i
      WHERE n.id=1 and n.iter=m.iter
      GROUP BY m.i, n.j, m.iter
   ) m ) pred,
   (SELECT *, rank() over (partition by m.i order by v desc) as rank FROM one_hot m) test
WHERE pred.i=test.i and pred.rank = 1 and test.rank=1
GROUP BY iter, pred.j=test.j
HAVING (pred.j=test.j)=true
ORDER BY iter
;`
```

Do let me know if I am wrong in my understanding. I have tried several methods but no success. I am also giving you screenshot of the output and definitely want execution time of each iteration next to it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7KdB.png)

Most of the time I got syntax error. I was trying to save the start and end time of each iteration but no success. I have tried EXPLAIN ANALYZE as well but it does not give the desired output.

Comment: Hi - recursion in SQL is not the same as a loop in a coding language. It is a way of simplifying how to write a query from a user perspective, it does not necessarily reflect how the query optimiser will choose to execute the query. Therefore trying to get the execution time of each “loop” of a recursion is meaningless as there is (or at least maybe) no loop - all you can tell is the start and end time of the overall query

Comment: It means that there is no possible way ?

Comment: It's not just that there isn't a way of doing it, what you are trying to do doesn't make any sense

Comment: If you know a way then please let me know. it may be meaningless for many but it is meaningful to me at least.

Comment: I meant it is meaningless in terms of what is actually being executed. There is no looping/iteration and therefore there are no iterations for you to get the duration of. So it’s not a case of not being able to calculate the duration of an activity, the activity itself doesn’t exist